# Java Autoboxing/Unboxing and Generic Type issue

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing, unboxing

I'm testing my knowledge on Generics in Java, and I'm coming across an issue.

The code

```
return (t%2==0);
```

in my IsEven.java wont compile, as well as

```
int comparison = t.compareTo(memberT);
```

in my GreaterThan.java

I assume this is an error with how I set up the Generic typing of the class? Any additional help would be appreciated.

**ArrayTester.java**

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ArrayTester<T> {

    private T[] myArray;
    CustomTest<T> tester;

    public ArrayTester(T[] tArray, CustomTest<T> cTest)
    {
        myArray = tArray.clone();
        tester = cTest;
        Arrays.sort(myArray);
    }

    public void printIfValid()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(tester.test(myArray[i]))
            {
                System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int countIfValid()
    {
        int tracker = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(tester.test(myArray[i]))
            {
                tracker++;
            }
        }
        return tracker;
    }

}
```

**CustomTest.java**

```
public interface CustomTest<T> {
    public boolean test(T t);
}
```

**AllLower.java**

```
public class AllLower implements CustomTest<String> {

    public boolean test(String t) {
        String lowerCaseVersion = t.toLowerCase();
        return t.equals(lowerCaseVersion);
    }    
}
```

**GreaterThan.java**

```
public class GreaterThan<T extends Object> implements CustomTest<T> {

    T memberT;

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        int comparison = t.compareTo(memberT); //why doesnt this work?
        if(comparison == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public GreaterThan(T t)
    {
        memberT = t;
    }

}
```

**ECTester.java**

```
public class ECTester {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Integer[] intArray = {2, 8, 6, 7, 4, 10, 3, 1, 9, 5};
                Double[] dblArray = {11.9, 12.2, 5.4, 0.2, 3.3, 3.9, 4.2, 1.1, 123456.0, 10.0001};
                String[] strArray = {"Why", "is", "A", "raven", "liKe", "a", "wriTing", "desk?"};

                ArrayTester<Integer> intTest = new ArrayTester<Integer>(intArray, new IsEven<Integer>());
                ArrayTester<Double> dblTest = new ArrayTester<Double>(dblArray, new IsEven<Double>());
                ArrayTester<String> strTest = new ArrayTester<String>(strArray, new AllLower());
                ArrayTester<Integer> intCompare = new ArrayTester<Integer>(intArray, new GreaterThan<Integer>(4));
                ArrayTester<Double> dblCompare = new ArrayTester<Double>(dblArray, new GreaterThan<Double>(4.5));
                ArrayTester<String> strCompare = new ArrayTester<String>(strArray, new GreaterThan<String>("last"));

                System.out.println("There are " + intTest.countIfValid() + " valid integers");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                intTest.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("There are " + dblTest.countIfValid() + " valid doubles");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                dblTest.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("There are " + strTest.countIfValid() + " valid strings");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                strTest.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("There are " + intCompare.countIfValid() + " integers greater than 4");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                intCompare.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("There are " + dblCompare.countIfValid() + " doubles greater than 4.5");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                dblCompare.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();

                System.out.println("There are " + strCompare.countIfValid() + " strings greater than \"last\"");
                System.out.println("They are: ");
                strCompare.printIfValid();

                System.out.println();


        }
}
```

**IsEven.java**

```
public class IsEven<T extends Number> implements CustomTest<T>{

    @Override
    public boolean test(T t) {
        return (t%2==0);
    }
    //Can't figure out why it wont accept this
}
```

Comment: `%` can not be used with objects, and `Number` is an object. Also, `Object` does not have a `compareTo` method, you would need `T extends Comparable<? super T>`

Comment: The second part fixed my error, I just mistakenly assumed that all objects had the compareTo method. However I still do not understand what I should do about the Number situation. I thought the whole point of autoboxing/unboxing was that it would automatically convert it to a primative type?

Comment: That works for boxed versions of those types, like `Integer`, `Long`, `Short`. `Number` is not one of those types.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately numeric operators like `%` aren't available as polymorphic constructs: the type of the operands needs to be known at compile time, which means you can't use it with an arbitrary `Number`.

And autoboxing/unboxing only applies when going from a specific primitive wrapper type (e.g. `java.lang.Integer`) to the corresponding primitive type (i.e. `int`); there is no primitive counterpart of `Number` to unbox to.

What you can do is either use `longValue()` or `doubleValue()` to pull out a `long` or `double` that you *can* use `%` with, or possibly use an if/else chain with `instanceof` checks. This won't completely solve your problem because `Number` is an open type -- non-primitive implementations exist. (`BigInteger` and `BigDecimal` are the well-known ones, but third-party libraries can add their own `Number` implementations as well.)

As for your other question about `compareTo()`, as mentioned in the comments above, you need `T extends Comparable<? super T>` to ensure that the `compareTo()` method exists.